# Looking for Firefox addon to auto apply CSS

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there an add-on(way) to auto add CSS rules on the browser level?

For example, I write a rule `p {color:red}`, and  subsequent all the pages loaded in Firefox will have that rule present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misinterpreted your question, but I believe [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) is the add-on you are looking for.